Не могу запустить код c pyqtgraph и pyAudio
Взял код тут https://github.com/takaT6/realtime-spectrum-analyzer/blob/main/SpectrumAnalyzer.py
Оказалось, что он немного устарел и нужно внести некоторые изменения. Пробовал следовать подсказкам PyCharm, но ничего не получилось.
Проблема в устаревших методах self.win=pg.GraphicsWindow() и self.plt=self.win.addPlot(). Может и дальше что-то пойдет под замену, но я уже застрял на addPlot().
Помогите внести исправления в коде.
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets,QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import sys
#音声関係のライブラリ
import pyaudio
class MainWindow():#(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        # self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        
        #マイクインプット設定
        self.CHUNK=1024         #1度に読み取る音声のデータ幅
        self.RATE=16000             #サンプリング周波数
        self.update_seconds=50      #更新時間[ms]
        self.audio=pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream=self.audio.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                                    channels=1,
                                    rate=self.RATE,
                                    input=True,
                                    frames_per_buffer=self.CHUNK)

        #音声データの格納場所(プロットデータ)
        self.data=np.zeros(self.CHUNK)
        self.axis=np.fft.fftfreq(len(self.data), d=1.0/self.RATE)

        #プロット初期設定
        self.win=pg.GraphicsWindow()
        self.win.setWindowTitle("SpectrumAnalyzer")
        self.plt=self.win.addPlot() #プロットのビジュアル関係
        self.plt.setYRange(0,100)    #y軸の制限

        # self.graphWidget = PlotWidget()
        # self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        # self.data_line =  self.graphWidget.plot()

        #アップデート時間設定
        self.timer=QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.timer.start(self.update_seconds)    #10msごとにupdateを呼び出し

    def update(self):
        self.data=np.append(self.data,self.AudioInput())
        if len(self.data)/1024 > 10:
            self.data=self.data[1024:]
        self.fft_data=self.FFT_AMP(self.data)
        self.axis=np.fft.fftfreq(len(self.data), d=1.0/self.RATE)
        self.plt.plot(x=self.axis, y=self.fft_data, clear=True, pen="y")  #symbol="o", symbolPen="y", symbolBrush="b")
        # self.data_line.setData(x=self.axis, y=self.fft_data, clear=True, pen="y") 

    def AudioInput(self):
        ret=self.stream.read(self.CHUNK)    #音声の読み取り(バイナリ) CHUNKが大きいとここで時間かかる
        #バイナリ → 数値(int16)に変換
        #32768.0=2^16で割ってるのは正規化(絶対値を1以下にすること)
        ret=np.frombuffer(ret, dtype="int16")/32768.0
        return ret

    def FFT_AMP(self, data):
        data=np.hamming(len(data))*data
        data=np.fft.fft(data)
        data=np.abs(data)
        return data

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win=MainWindow()
    # win.show()
    # if (sys.flags.interactive!=1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    #     QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Дополнение:
Даже при использовании библиотеки PyQt5 я продолжаю получать тоже самое и далее все идет по цепочке


Владимир, код, который вы предоставили, для меня работает (Windows 7, Python 7, PyQt5) и с чего вы решили,  что он немного устарел и нужно внести некоторые изменения. Какие изменения вы собираетесь вносить?

Привет, S.NicK! БЫть может проблема в том, что я использую PyQT6. Проверю для себя с PyQt5.

Владимир, все может быть, но вы что получаете какую-то ошибку? Код, на который вы ссылаетесь написан на PySide6

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/217323/s-nick даже с PyQt5 получаю ту же проблему. Странно, что у одних код запускается, а у других нет

Владимир, не надо добавлять сообщение об ошибке картинкой, всегда добавляйте полное сообщение обычным текстом. У вас претензии к библиотеке pyqtgraph , попробуйте ее обновить.

Владимир, кстати второй вариант с виджетом   PlotWidget. Раскомментируйте все  и закомментируйте строки где есть self.win или self.plt . Таким образом вы избавитесь от pg.GraphicsWindow()
